# Gmail filters exact phrase matching

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm having issues with my Gmail filter. It seems to be performing some type of fuzzy matching even though I explicitly defined exact phrase matching. My filter is:

```
Has the words: 
{"unsubscribe" “update your preferences” “opt out” "opt-out" "SafeUnsubscribe" 
 "unsubscribing" "stop receiving" "subscribed" "promotional email" "prefer not" 
 "Manage Your Preferences"}
```

In other words, I want it to filter the email if it contains any of those exact phrases. However, when I view the filtered results, it includes matches that don't have the exact phrases that I have defined. Any idea how to fix this issue/make it behave as I intended? I've also checked the raw message source to see if it contains any of these exact phrases but to no success.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**try:**

```
(("unsubscribe" AND "update your preferences" AND "opt out" AND "opt-out" AND 
  "SafeUnsubscribe" AND "unsubscribing" AND "stop receiving" AND "subscribed" AND 
  "promotional email" AND "prefer not" AND "Manage Your Preferences"))
```

**or:**

```
(("unsubscribe" OR "update your preferences" OR "opt out" OR "opt-out" OR 
  "SafeUnsubscribe" OR "unsubscribing" OR "stop receiving" OR "subscribed" OR 
  "promotional email" OR "prefer not" OR "Manage Your Preferences"))
```